# How do you update leaflet marker position every 2 seconds using getJSON response?

Tags: json, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm building a get user location on a JSON file every 2 seconds on a JSON response, I tried this code below but the marker is not showing.

```
 locate();
 var map = L.map('map', {scrollWheelZoom:true}).setView([51.505, -0.09], 15);
 L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
 var myMovingMarker;
 function locate() {
   $.getJSON('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/vehicle/get_vehicle_location/2',
     function(response) {
       var longitude = response['longtitude'];
       var latitude = response['latitude'];
       document.getElementById("coordinates").innerHTML = 
         "<span style='font-weight: bold;''>Longitude:</span> "
         + longitude + " | <span style='font-weight: bold;''>Latitude:</span> "
         + latitude + " ";  

       if (!myMovingMarker) {
         myMovingMarker = L.marker([latitude,longitude]).addTo(map);
       }
       myMovingMarker.setLatLng([latitude,longitude]).update();  
       setTimeout(locate, 2000);
     });
 }
```

Comment: You use the variables `longtitude` *and* `longitude`. Are these typos?

Comment: wher are the typos?

Comment: `var longtitude = response['longtitude'];`

Comment: long**t**itude vs longitude

Comment: i am storing the data from the json file to a variable

Comment: `longtitude` is spelled incorrectly. You need to name it `longitude`. The code further down (where you create/set the marker) has it spelled correctly.

Comment: @Cross whatever the name of your variable, you just need to be consistent and use the exact same spelling throughout your code to refer to that variable. Otherwise it refers to another one, which is probably undefined.

Comment: @ghybs its a typo sorry i update my question

Comment: @Cross Thank you for the correction. Would you be able to reproduce your issue on Plunker / JSBin / JSFiddle? You can use dummy data for your AJAX call. Except for the unknown `.update()` method on your marker, it does not look like your code would be that bad.

Comment: @ghybs thank you for your answer. the answer is your answer.